# How do you check if you are in an interactive qmake session ? I want to use qmake prompt()

Tags: qt, qmake, interactive

I want to make an interactive "qmake -makefile session" with this mockup.pro file :

```
message("Plugin setup,")
message("choose the plugins you want to be compiled :")

answer=$$prompt("Dummy ? (y/N)")
equals(answer,"y"){
    SUBDIRS+= dummy
}
```

This is fine when launched from an interactive shell, but AFAIK, qmake launched from QtCreator outputs in the "Compilation output" pane, and is not interactive, hence the prompt blocks.

Is this supported?

QMake 3.1, QtCreator 4.11

---

When I check with :

```
IS_INT = $$system(echo $-)
```

IS_INT is always empty, aka the secondary shell is not interactive.

Comment: Probably not supported. Solutions: run qmake in a shell. Allow environment variable overrides anf set the right variables in QtC project settings. (I invite anybody to write a proper answer(s) for these options.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hyde suggested, and in the other direction, to not disturb packagers nor build farms, will allow users to get guided with a flag CONFIG+=INTERACTIVE_QMAKE.

```
INTERACTIVE_QMAKE{
    answer=$$prompt("Dummy ? (y/N)")
    equals(answer,"y"):{
        SUBDIRS+= dummy
    }
}
!INTERACTIVE_QMAKE{
    # The plugins you want compiled by default
    SUBDIRS+= dummy
}
```

CMake on its way for Qt6, this will do it.